# python 2.7 Beautifulsoup error (for windows)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm now studying crawling in python 2.7. I'm getting the following error

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

[image: img]

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Don't link to off-site resources.  **Add all relevant resources directly in your question**.

Comment: Please update your question to include the source code that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when you imported BeautifulSoup you imported the library or module. Instead of importing the BeautifulSoup class. So to fix your issue call it like so.

```
BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
```

Comment: Oh! bro thank u for helping me. the error is solved. it works well.